# Rails - Calling a model method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Basically, I have a datetime field in my model and I want to return it as an age. My question is, how do I make @student_age an array of ages?

The top image is my controller. 
The bottom image is my model method, which inputs the SQL query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont quite get what you want but if you want your query automatically returns an array you can do this.

In rails 4 you can add pluck to return an array.

```
Student.select('date_part("year",age(dob)').pluck(:date_part)
```

In rails 3 you can do this.

```
Student.select('date_part("year",age(dob)').collect{|x| x.date_part}
```

Output will be like this
[24, 13, 56, 34]

Comment: Am I supposed to add this in my controller?

Answer (score 1):

```
Student.select('date_part("year", age(dob))')
```